# Statistic analysis of two groups

Tags: spss, anova, t-test

i need to analyze this data. Tried with anova and independent t-test but i have no results.
i appreciate your comments

Group   Biomass
1  3876 3876 3875
2  4016 4016 4016

Values represent area as growth

Answer (score 0):

Are these several observations of the same thing..? to use t test or anova you would typically need two groups (or one group with a repeated measure) and at least one factor which you expect to change the outcome of a measurement between the groups or different points in time